# Printing a Password Generator

Tags: java

So,  I am trying to make a password generator that I can use for furure Applications etc.

So far i have gotten what characters I want to use and have made a SecureRandom to put them in a certain order.

How exactly should I lay this out. Any suggestions on how I should make it print the characters out, and how should I go about printing the 10 character password?

here is the code so far :

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Random;


public class Generator {

public static void main(String [] args){

    String[] symbols = {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"};
    int length = 10;
    Random random = new SecureRandom(); 
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(length);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        int indexRandom = random.nextInt( symbols.length );
        sb.append( symbols[indexRandom] );
    }
    String password = sb.toString();

}

}
```

*basically what I am asking is how would I get this to print out the 10 character password that is randomly generated.*

Comment: `System.out.println()` not working for you?

Comment: @Matt Ball. Nope, it's not wanting to show any numbers in the Console after I run the application.

Comment: print? print to console or to a paper?

Comment: @sanket why would you ever recommend that when you've already got a string...?

Comment: Well i thought he wanted to extract charaters and print them one by one...

Comment: Console, like using    System.out.println(). I forgot to use the string "password" to make it print.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add  `System.out.println(password);` to the code. It worked for me.
Btw, not sure why its not working in your console. It worked for me with Eclipse.

Comment: Thank you, this printed it just fine. I forgot to put the string "password".

Answer (score 2):

You can make simple UI on Swing with label and button "Generate". Also it will let you make your generation mechanism configurable. Also use

```
new Random(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis())
```

instead. Otherwise you will loose the availability to control the seed of randomness.